# Performance Difference between SYSDATE and variable INSERT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a program currently set up like so...

```
For rec in main_cursor LOOP
   INSERT INTO table_name VALUES( rec.value, SYSDATE);
END LOOP;
```

Is it better to assign sysdate to a variable first ie

```
var_date := SYSDATE;
For rec in main_cursor LOOP
    INSERT INTO table_name VALUES( rec.value, var_date);
END LOOP;
```

In my situation it only does this around 10k times, but what if I scaled that to a very large data set?

Furthermore, how would I go about finding the answer to this question myself?  I could create two test programs, but even running the same program twice will give a variable execution time(depending on caching, others using database?).  I'm using SQLDeveloper.

Comment: The question about variable assigment's performance impact is irrelevant when you're inserting records one-by-one. It's running the insert in the loop that will limit your scaling.

Answer (score 3):

The two approaches will give different results, so the priority should be correctness.

If a single uniform value is acceptable then yes it will be faster, although I would not expect a huge overhead from repeatedly checking the system time.

I would test without the INSERT statement and maybe profile a few test runs.

Comment: They will give different results?  The column I'm inserting into is a DATE and the variable var_date would be typed as DATE also.  Would this still give different results?

Comment: I just mean the last insert statement might be executed some time after the first one, in which case it will get a later value for sysdate if you're evaluating it for every loop iteration.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  Date is accurate to the second.  This flew over my head because in my application I'm only looking at the day, I'm not getting that granular with the data.

Comment: It depends what time you start and how big the loop is. It could well be the next day by the time it finishes. Loops like this tend not to be particularly fast.

Answer (score 3):

While you may get some slight performance gains at the expense of absolute timestamp accuracy between the first and last insert, if you really want to boost performance you should look to see if you can avoid the loop and instead either code a single bulk insert that uses the same query that is driving your main_Cursor

insert into table_name (select ..... from);

Or by using the main_cursor to do a bulk collect fetch followed by a bulk insert using FORALL.

This may not be possible, of course, if you loop is doing other things that need to be iterative tasks and I have no knowledge of what exactly your code is doing. But unless you are processing millions of rows, I very much doubt that the change to how you call sysdate is going to make a huge difference in your timing.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I don't know why I'm even doing this you are right.  I use the cursor in a loop that needs to be in a loop earlier in the program.  I just opened it back up to insert to the table I was comparing it to later, out of laziness and comfort I guess.

Comment: Well, there is definite safety in re-using a query as you are guaranteed that the results are what you've already tested, so I understand why going that route is appealing. But if you need to tune then tackling the big items like this is more likely to gain results than chipping away at the little things. And if you are already looping through that cursor out of necessity - can you move the insert into that first loop to avoid the second pass through the records?